# How to use log-rank test for panel data?

Tags: survival, panel-data, logrank-test

Is it possible, and if yes how, to compute log-rank test to compare effects in (unbalanced) panel data, i.e. longitudinal study ? What are the possible problems which might arise ?

Comment: Please provide more details about the nature of your study and what you are trying to accomplish. Otherwise it will be difficult to provide a useful answer.